# Parse json request in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.android, response

I´ve searched for a long time but without success...

**I want to parse a json response from an API in Xamarin.Android.**

My json responsee is like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "21",
    "date": "2018-01-01",
    "name": "Name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "date": "2018-01-02",
    "name": "Name2",
  }
]
```

As you see, it contains 2 rows. The numer of rows can change. Sometimes the there are 6 rows but sometimes only 2...

So i want to get the value of each id, date and name tag, for each row.
I tryed with an for each loop but don't succeed...

Could someone help me with DataSet and DataTable?

I saw this code but get an error with DataSet and DataTable:

```
string json = @"{
  'Table1': [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'item': 'item 0'
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'item': 'item 1'
    }
  ]
}";

DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);

DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Table1"];

Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Rows.Count);
// 2

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["id"] + " - " + row["item"]);
}
// 0 - item 0
// 1 - item 1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what about newtonsoft json?

Comment: Yes i tryed, but didn´t undesrstand... Could you help me with DataSet and DataTable ? This is, what i dont understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` function

Make a `ObjModel` class to carry your json data.

```
public class ObjModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

ObjModel[] datas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjModel[]>(jsonData);
```

c# online:https://dotnetfiddle.net/UybCQ1

if you want to `DeserializeObject` to `DataTable` it can work too.

```
DataTable  dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString2);

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
  Console.WriteLine(row["id"]);
}
```

Comment: It works! Is there any way to get the number of rows?

Comment: simple way you can use `for loop` to count array then the index be your number.https://dotnetfiddle.net/UybCQ1  you can add the number in to your model

Comment: look like this. `string jsonString2 = "[{\"id\": \"21\",\"date\": \"2018-01-01\",\"name\": \"Name1\"},{\"id\": \"22\",\"date\": \"2018-01-02\", \"name\": \"Name2\"}]";`

Comment: If your string want to contain `"` double quotes another way you need to add \ before double quotes

Comment: Could you cancle your code on dotnetfiddle.net, so that i can take a look at the for loop again?